# graphviz: Create new node with this same label

Tags: graphviz

I'm starting working with graphviz and I have problem with creating new nodes with this same label. 
For example for word "sentence" I would like to create graph with 8 nodes:
s -> e -> n -> t -> e -> n -> c -> e
Now I'm receiving graph with only 5 nodes (one "e" instead of 3 and one "n" instead of 2). I need to create more nodes with this same label (value).

Example of my problem may be this image http://rdftwig.sourceforge.net/paper/diagrams/bfsdeep.png where there are 2 nodes with value "C", "E" and "D".

Is it possible? If it is possible how can I access in my example with word "sentence" first, second or third "e" node?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could define your nodes explicitly and set the label for them. Then each node has an unique id, but can have the same labels. Consider this example:

```
strict graph G {
    1 [label="A"];
    2 [label="B"];
    3 [label="B"];
    4 [label="A"];
    1 -- 2;
    2 -- 3;
    3 -- 4;
}
```

which will output (with `dot`):

[image: Nodes with same labels]

Comment: This worked for me, but its tedious as hell.  It would be nice to have a flag like repeatnode=false, so when we do something like

a -> b
b -> c
c -> d
d -> a

It will create a new 'a' automatically,

Comment: This is what's refreshing about dot, it's just plain simple and it works, I wish more technologies worked like dot...

Answer (score 0):

It might sound wired, but just put a whitespace at the end of the character that repeated will solve the problem.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Instead just use the key to be unique, as @maehler said. The keys are for the programmer and not displayed in the graph. A simple whitespace is not visible, nor easy to remember or self explanatory.